# AWS CLI - No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-emr

Im using the CLI for AWS to create a cluster and use the parameters from a json file. Here is the CLI command string Im using:

```
aws emr create-cluster --name "Big Matrix Re Run 1" --ami-version 3.1.0 --steps file://Segmentgroup1.json --release-label --instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m3.xlarge InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType=m3.xlarge --auto-terminate
```

My json file (Segmentgroup1.json) is in the same folder in which Im running the AWS command string from, but I keep getting the following error:

```
No JSON object could be decoded
```

Based on what Ive found its not finding the json file. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you sanity checked the JSON file's validity e.g. [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)

Comment: looks like that might be it...strange that its worked on my other machine, but not my mac.

Answer (score 32):

I ran into the same problem under my Mac, and I found the cause is the path for the json file instead of the content of the json file. To make it right:

- You need to append `file://` protocol as the prefix for your path
- and use absolute path to your JSON file as parameter

Try something like this:

`aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://<absolute_path_to_json>/your_json.json`

If you don't want to hard code the file path, you may use command like `pwd` to do this:

`` aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://`pwd`/your_json.json ``

Comment: Thanks. Absolute path is not a must. I can use `file://test.json` as long as test.json is in the current folder

Comment: @HarryNg Thanks, I was not aware of this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example command that works on Windows, where the file path syntax is a little different:

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace "EC2 Memory Usage" --metric-data file://C:\Users\Joe\mycode\metric.json
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem that you are facing here is because of the way `AWS CLI` commands are exposed. They can either take `JSON` (as a string) directly from the command line or as a JSON file.

If you don't explicitly specify your intention by providing the file path in the `URI` format (prefixed with `file://`), the command treats the file path itself as a JSON string and gives you this error.